# How to return @Html.ActionLink

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, html-helper

I am writing a Html Helper for my MVC 3 project.

I want to return the MvcHtmlString like "@Html.ActionLink(xxxxx)", what should I write?

Currently I have this code:

```
        public static MvcHtmlString SetFeaturedFor<TModel, TValue>(this HtmlHelper<TModel> htmlHelper,Expression<Func<TModel, TValue>> expression)
    {
        var isFeatured =Convert.ToBoolean(ModelMetadata.FromLambdaExpression(expression, htmlHelper.ViewData).Model.ToString());

        string result = "Html.ActionLink(Delete, DeleteComment, Admin, new { Id = @thisComment.CommentId }, null)";

        return MvcHtmlString.Create(result);
    }
```

It returns the whole string, but I want the rendered string. So what should I do?

### Update

Looks like I can return this directly:

```
        public static MvcHtmlString SetFeaturedFor<TModel, TValue>(this HtmlHelper<TModel> htmlHelper,Expression<Func<TModel, TValue>> expression)
    {
        var isFeatured =Convert.ToBoolean(ModelMetadata.FromLambdaExpression(expression, htmlHelper.ViewData).Model.ToString());
        
        string indicatorText = (isFeatured) ? "Unset Featured" : "Set Featured";
        
        return htmlHelper.ActionLink(indicatorText, "SetFeaturedIncident", "Admin", null, null);
    }
```

Need to import System.Web.Routing namespace.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove the quotes (you want to call the function, not just store the code in a string) and the `@` (that's Razor, not C# anyways). You might need to change `Html` to whatever you called the helper parameter in your (presumably) extension method.

Also, `Html.ActionLink` already returns `MvcHtmlString` so you can just put it directly after `return`.